# Como transformar este array num array de 4 índices?

Tags: php, array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Camaquã,Cavalhada,Cristal,Hípica
    )
```

Preciso transformar o `array` acima num array de 4 índices conforme pode ser visto abaixo.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Camaquã
        [1] => Cavalhada
        [2] => Cristal
        [3] => Hípica
   )
```

Comment: `explode()` não resolveu?

Comment: Acho que não sei fazer ...

Comment: [Mas você já usou isso várias vezes!](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4110+array+explode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é fácil, utilize o famoso `explode`

```
<?php    

$array = array('Camaquã,Cavalhada,Cristal,Hípica');  // Possivelmente está assim.
$stringAux = rtrim($array['0'],','); // isto irá remover a ultima "," caso exista "Hípica,"
$array_resultado = explode(',', $stringAux); // Divide cada ","

var_dump($array_resultado);

// RESULTADO (VAR_DUMP):  
//array(4) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(8) "Camaquã"
//  [1]=>
//  string(9) "Cavalhada"
//  [2]=>
//  string(7) "Cristal"
//  [3]=>
//  string(7) "Hípica"
//}
```

*Use sempre `var_dump` para ver o que a variável está carregando, será muito mais fácil para aprender/desenvolver, logicamente remova quando for publica-lo.*

Teste [isto aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6628ed2a2bd81708c2e9e59b5cd51a9e44c43b15)!